# Cauchy Riemann Equations valid for $U$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic on an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{C}$, then the Cauchy Riemann equations for $f$ hold in $U$.

My question is, how do the Cauchy-Riemann equations differ on an open set $U$ versus a function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$? Not sure how to prove this.

Comment: tell me what is your definition of analytic function?? I am sure it is not something which satisfies cauchy riemann equation.... Do you  get what i said?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik derivative exists as the limit of a difference quotient

Comment: so you have to prove cauchy riemann holds using that definition... I do not understand your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is holomorphic iff
$$
f(z+w)-f(z) = \gamma w + \omega(w) |w|
$$
where 
$$
\lim_{|w|\to 0}\omega(w)=0
$$
where $z,w\in \mathbb{C}$.
Now, let $w = h+ik$, where $h,k \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have, if $f$ is differentiable in the real sense:
$$
\gamma = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big|_{(z)} \qquad i\gamma=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big|_{(z)}
$$
which implies
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0.
$$
Letting now $f=u+iv$  and equating real and imaginary parts we have precisely the Cauchy Riemann equations:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =   \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \qquad \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In the difference quotient consider two different paths converging to $0$: one along the real axis and one along the imaginary axis.